# Hover on 3D carousel element in CSS only

Tags: css, 3d, hover, css-animations, carousel

I'm trying to figure out how to make the carousel element stand still when hovered (keep it in the same position where the cursor is) but it keeps changing the position to the center of the whole thing like in this picture:

[image]

The idea is to build a 3D carousel that rotates till the user hovers over it, then it stops, the hovered element grows (inviting to click on it), and if unhover animation continues, but for some reason element keeps changing position :c

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <!-- <link rel="stylesheet" href="../css/test.css"> -->
  <title>Document</title>
</head>
<style>
  body {
    height: 100vh;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
  }
  
  .slider {
    position: relative;
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    transform-style: preserve-3d;
    animation: rotate 30s linear infinite;
  }
  
  @keyframes rotate {
    0% {
      transform: perspective(1000px) rotateY(0deg);
    }
    100% {
      transform: perspective(1000px) rotateY(360deg);
    }
  }
  
  .slider div {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    transform-origin: center;
    transform-style: preserve-3d;
    transform: rotateY(calc(var(--i)*40deg)) translateZ(350px);
    background-color: black;
  }
  
  .slider img {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    object-fit: cover;
    transition: 2s;
  }
  
  .slider div:hover {
    transform: translateY(-50px) scale(1.2);
  }
  
  .slider:hover {
    animation-play-state: paused;
  }
</style>

<body>
  <div class="slider">
    <div style="--i:1"><img src=""></div>
    <div style="--i:2"><img src=""></div>
    <div style="--i:3"><img src=""></div>
    <div style="--i:4"><img src=""></div>
    <div style="--i:5"><img src=""></div>
    <div style="--i:6"><img src=""></div>
    <div style="--i:7"><img src=""></div>
    <div style="--i:8"><img src=""></div>
    <div style="--i:9"><img src=""></div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Do you guys know any solutions?

Answer (score 0):

Apply the transformation to the image on hover instead of the div. I also updated the code a little to optimize it using CSS grid instead of absolute position:

```css
body {
  height: 100vh;
  margin: 0;
  display: grid;
  place-content: center;
}

.slider {
  display: grid;
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
  animation: rotate 30s linear infinite;
}

@keyframes rotate {
  0% {
    transform: perspective(1000px) rotateY(0deg);
  }
  100% {
    transform: perspective(1000px) rotateY(360deg);
  }
}

.slider div {
  grid-area: 1/1;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
  transform: rotateY(calc(var(--i)*40deg)) translateZ(250px);
}

.slider img {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  object-fit: cover;
  transition: 1s;
}

.slider div:hover img{
  transform: translateY(-50px) scale(1.2);
}

.slider:hover {
  animation-play-state: paused;
}
```

```html
<div class="slider">
  <div style="--i:1"><img src="https://picsum.photos/id/1051/200/200"></div>
  <div style="--i:2"><img src="https://picsum.photos/id/1051/200/200"></div>
  <div style="--i:3"><img src="https://picsum.photos/id/1051/200/200"></div>
  <div style="--i:4"><img src="https://picsum.photos/id/1051/200/200"></div>
  <div style="--i:5"><img src="https://picsum.photos/id/1051/200/200"></div>
  <div style="--i:6"><img src="https://picsum.photos/id/1051/200/200"></div>
  <div style="--i:7"><img src="https://picsum.photos/id/1051/200/200"></div>
  <div style="--i:8"><img src="https://picsum.photos/id/1051/200/200"></div>
  <div style="--i:9"><img src="https://picsum.photos/id/1051/200/200"></div>
</div>
```